# Getting a exception when I use a picklist with pojo

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

I´m trying to use the picklist component so I test the picklist example that is in the primefaces site using String and it work just fine, but when I try to use a pojo I get a exception, here´s the code and the exception:

xhtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:head>
<title>PickList Test</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
        <h:form id="form">
                 <p:pickList value="#{pickListBean.employeeList}" var="employee" itemLabel="#{employee.employeeName}" itemValue="#{employee.employeeCode}" />  
                 <p:commandButton value="Save" action="#{pickListBean.message}" style="margin-left: 12px;"/>
        </h:form>


</h:body>
</html>
```

bean

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class PickListBean {
@EJB
private BussinessList bl = new BussinessList();
private DualListModel<Employee> employeeList;

private Employee employee;
/**
* Creates a new instance of PickListBean
*/
public PickListBean() {
List<Employee> source = new ArrayList<Employee>();
List<Employee> target = new ArrayList<Employee>();
source = bl.getEmployee();
employeeList = new DualListModel<Employee>(source, target);
}
public void message(){
System.out.println("CommandButton is working");
}
public DualListModel<Employee> getEmployeeList() {
return employeeList;
}

public void setEmployeeList(DualListModel<Employee> employeeList) {
this.employeeList = employeeList;
}
public Employee getEmployee() {
return employee;
}

public void setEmployee(Employee employee) {
this.employee= employee;
}
}
```

exception

```
om.sun.faces.mgbean.ManagedBeanCreationException: Cant instantiate class:      managedBean.PickListBean.
at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.newBeanInstance(BeanBuilder.java:191)
at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.build(BeanBuilder.java:100)
at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.createAndPush(BeanManager.java:409)
at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.create(BeanManager.java:269)
at com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.resolveBean(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:244)    
at com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.getValue(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:116)
at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
at com.sun.el.parser.AstIdentifier.getValue(AstIdentifier.java:116)
at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getBase(AstValue.java:151)
at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:200)
at com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:226)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109)
at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:194)
at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:182)
at javax.faces.component.UIOutput.getValue(UIOutput.java:174)
at javax.faces.component.UIInput.getValue(UIInput.java:291)
at  org.primefaces.component.picklist.PickListRenderer.encodeMarkup(PickListRenderer.java:66)
at org.primefaces.component.picklist.PickListRenderer.encodeEnd(PickListRenderer.java:59)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:924)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1863)
at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:176)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:894)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1856)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
at    com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrat    egy.java:443)
at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:131)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:647)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
at   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:3    44)
at  org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:70)
at    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:316)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:260)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:188)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
at     org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288    )
at    org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
at  org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java    :55)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadI    OStrategy.java:135)
at  org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at negocio.ListagemNegocio.getFuncionarios(ListagemNegocio.java:62)
at managedBean.PickListBean.<init>(PickListBean.java:36)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at     sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
at  sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.ja    va:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:372)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:325)
at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.newBeanInstance(BeanBuilder.java:186)
... 63 more
```

Comment: Employee is `Serializable`?

Comment: Yes vels4j, is Serializable...

Comment: update complete stack trace.

Comment: Done...Its already updated...

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at negocio.ListagemNegocio.getFuncionarios(ListagemNegocio.java:62)
  what about this one?

Comment: its nothing to do with Primefaces, error in your code.

Comment: vels4j and seph, the problem is in the serializable object as vels4j suspect cuz I test with a no serializable object and it works just fine. The problem is that i´m using ejb+netbeans and the object is automatically generate. Any tip of how to work with picklist using serializable object???

Answer (score -1):

Replace this by class objects ,

```
List<Employee> source = new ArrayList<Employee>();
List<Employee> target = new ArrayList<Employee>();
```

as,

```
List<employee> source = new ArrayList<employee>();
List<employee> target = new ArrayList<employee>();
```